# Determine if values in String Array are equal without a massive loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to compare the values in a string array so they are never equal, and if they are, they have to be changed. I did a really badly looking while for that, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient solution.

```
String[] myAnswers = new String[myWords.size()];
myAnswers[0] = "s";
myAnswers[1] = "s";
myAnswers[2] = "s";
myAnswers[3] = "s";
myAnswers[4] = "s";
myAnswers[5] = "s";

while (myAnswers[0].equals(myAnswers[1]) || myAnswers[0].equals(myAnswers[2])
        || myAnswers[0].equals(myAnswers[3]) || myAnswers[0].equals(myAnswers[4])
        || myAnswers[1].equals(myAnswers[2]) || myAnswers[1].equals(myAnswers[3])
        || myAnswers[1].equals(myAnswers[4]) || myAnswers[2].equals(myAnswers[3])
        || myAnswers[2].equals(myAnswers[4]) || myAnswers[3].equals(myAnswers[4])
        || myAnswers[5].equals(myAnswers[0]) || myAnswers[5].equals(myAnswers[1])
        || myAnswers[5].equals(myAnswers[2]) || myAnswers[5].equals(myAnswers[3])
        || myAnswers[5].equals(myAnswers[4])) {

    // Change values

}
```

Comment: What is the logic behind `//Change values`

Answer (score 1):

Convert array to a HashSet (It will remove dupicates)

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

and then

```
while(mySet.size!=1){
//change values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashmap , and check if the key is duplicate, change if duplicate

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all the values are equal using `Arrays.stream` while comparing all values to the first one in the array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] myAnswers = new String[6];
    myAnswers[0] = "s";
    myAnswers[1] = "s";
    myAnswers[2] = "s";
    myAnswers[3] = "s";
    myAnswers[4] = "s";
    myAnswers[5] = "s";

    if (Arrays.stream(myAnswers)
            .allMatch(it -> it.equals(myAnswers[0]))) {
        System.out.println("All values equal");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Not all values equal");
    }

    String[] moreOfMyAnswers = new String[6];
    moreOfMyAnswers[0] = "s";
    moreOfMyAnswers[1] = "s";
    moreOfMyAnswers[2] = "S"; // this one is different
    moreOfMyAnswers[3] = "s";
    moreOfMyAnswers[4] = "s";
    moreOfMyAnswers[5] = "s";

    if (Arrays.stream(moreOfMyAnswers)
            .allMatch(it -> it.equals(moreOfMyAnswers[0]))) {
        System.out.println("All values equal");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Not all values equal");
    }
}
```

Output is this:

```
All values equal
Not all values equal
```

Comment: I tried to apply this in a loop but in brings a nullpointerexcpection on Arrays.stream(moreOfMyAnswers)
            .allMatch(it -> it.equals(moreOfMyAnswers[0])

Comment: @CroquetaFregidaAmbPastanaga what does the error message state? Do you have Java 8? Can you edit your question and put the code you tried and the error message in?